# Using the SIRI API in JavaScript - wrong subscription request XML structure

Tags: javascript, ajax, pebble-sdk, pebble-js, siri-xml

I'm in the process of creating a Pebble application in JavaScript that displays bus times for my city. I'm currently having difficulties sending an AJAX request to the relevant API. My code is below:

```
var UI = require('ui'); 
var ajax = require('ajax');
var card = new UI.Card({ 
    title:'Bus data', 
    subtitle:'Fetching...' }); 
ajax({ 
    url: "http://siri.nxtbus.act.gov.au:11000/APIKEY/pt/service.xml", 
    method: "post", 
    type: 'xml', 
    data: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?><Siri version="2.0" xmlns:ns2="http://www.ifopt.org.uk/acsb" xmlns="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri" xmlns:ns4="http://datex2.eu/schema/2_0RC1/2_0" xmlns:ns3="http://www.ifopt.org.uk/ifopt"><ServiceRequest><RequestTimestamp>2013-12-29T12:58:29</RequestTimestamp><RequestorRef>APIKEY</RequestorRef><ProductionTimetableRequest version="2.0"><RequestTimestamp>2013-12-29T12:58:29</RequestTimestamp><ValidityPeriod><StartTime>2015-02-20T13:50:04+01:00</StartTime><EndTime>2015-02-21T13:50:04+01:00</EndTime></ValidityPeriod><Lines><LineDirection><LineRef>ACT_200</LineRef><DirectionRef>A</DirectionRef></LineDirection></Lines></ProductionTimetableRequest></ServiceRequest></Siri>' 
},  function(data) { 
        // Success! 
        console.log('Successfully fetched bus data!'); 
        console.log(data); }, 
    function(error) { 
        // Failure! 
        console.log('Failed fetching weather data: ' + error); 
    } 
);
```

However, this is the AJAX response I get:

```
<Siri xmlns="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri" xmlns:ns2="http://www.ifopt.org.uk/acsb" xmlns:ns3="http://www.ifopt.org.uk/ifopt" xmlns:ns4="http://datex2.eu/schema/2_0RC1/2_0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri ../siri.xsd">
<ServiceDelivery>
    <ResponseTimestamp>2015-02-20T16:44:41+11:00</ResponseTimestamp>
    <ProducerRef>ACT</ProducerRef>
    <Status>false</Status>
    <ErrorCondition>
        <OtherError number="103">
            <ErrorText>wrong subscription request XML structure</ErrorText>
        </OtherError>
    </ErrorCondition>
</ServiceDelivery>
</Siri>
```

I'm not sure why I'm receiving this response, and I'd really appreciate some assistance in this matter.

Here is the documentation for the SIRI API I'm using, in case you'd like to have a look: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3r1ipRAb5pKQnAxYi1ESEhOanc/view?usp=sharinghttps://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3r1ipRAb5pKQnAxYi1ESEhOanc/view?usp=sharing